# How to interact with python script on local server in Android

Tags: android, python

How to send user text for processing to python script running on a local server and get JSON object back and display that in our app.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not about android studio. If I were you, I would look to python web frameworks which can help you to create a REST API. I usually use Django for big and complex projects, Flask for simple http, Tornado for websockets. In your situation I'd rather use Flask with Mongo no-sql database.
You can also use something like Ngrok to share your local api through the internet. 
Here is the tutorial about flask, there are many of them in google, you can choose any. 
https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/build-simple-restful-api-with-python-and-flask-part-1-fae9ff66a706

If you have big project with complex backend, my advice will be to use Django and Django REST Framework, there is a lot of information about them in official docs, and also there are good courses on Udemy by Justin Mitchell.

Just follow some flask tutorials and it will be simple to implement what you want